# Can the Large Hadron Collider break the speed of light?

Tags: faster-than-light, large-hadron-collider

Can Large Hadron Collider experiments break the speed of light at some point in the future?

[image]

Comment: No. Just no. No.

Answer (score 3):

**No**. Not at the LHC and not at an even more powerful accelerator in the future. Now matter how much energy the accelerated particles acquire, they will never be able to surpass the speed of light. A massive particle like the ones at the LHC, i.e. one with non-vanishing rest mass, will not even reach the speed of light, it will only come arbitrarily close to it as you add more energy to the system.

Answer (score -6):

Actually, this might be possible. Mass is proportional to speed and light speed gives the limit at infinity, but this only accounts for particles with mass, for particles without mass this won't affect, I think. The eq. for relative mass becomes infinite for particle with least mass, but not zero mass. For objects with zero mass going at light speed , the eq. becomes 0/0, and for particles with more than light speed 0/-n, for any no. n. So Particle accelerators may break the speed of light for particles with no mass or, negative mass, for that fact, just thought of that. Anyway, it may be possible.

Comment: No. No, it isn't. Not at all.

Comment: what isn't? What are you referring to?

Comment: Possible to go faster than light. Or for particles without mass to go any speed besides the speed of light.

Comment: I did not say that particles without mass cannot go at any speed other than the speed of light, it is possible for an object at 0 mass to go at the speed of light, cause that particle with 0 mass goes like a photon, it can go at the speed of light. other hypothetical particles such as tachyons can only go faster than light, it is not possible for them to go less than the speed of light.

Comment: You did say that massless particles can go faster than the speed of light, in your last sentence.